# How to parse DTD node structure with MSXML6

Tags: delphi, dtd, msxml, msxml6, dtd-parsing

There are some stand-alone DTD files that I would like to parse in my Delphi application with MSXML6. The DTD file content looks similar to:

```
<!ELEMENT note (to,from,heading,body)>

<!ELEMENT to (#PCDATA)>
<!ATTLIST to
  type CDATA #FIXED "email"
  default CDATA #FIXED "you@foo.bar"
>

<!ELEMENT from (#PCDATA)>
<!ATTLIST from
  type CDATA #FIXED "email"
  default CDATA #FIXED "me@foo.bar"
>

<!ELEMENT heading (#PCDATA)>
<!ATTLIST heading
  type CDATA #FIXED "string"
>

<!ELEMENT body (#PCDATA)>
<!ATTLIST body
  type CDATA #FIXED "string"
>
```

Trying to load this data with MSXML fails with error message "Cannot have a DTD declaration outside of a DTD".

When wrapping the DTD into some DOCTYPE element like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE note [
... content of DTD file above ...
]>
<note/>
```

the parser succeeds but does not allow to iterate over the DTD structure. The (Delphi) code to load and display the document looks like this:

```
var
   XmlDoc : iXmlDomDocument2;
   i : integer;
begin
   XmlDoc := CoDomDocument60.Create();
   XmlDoc.SetProperty('NewParser', FALSE);
   XmlDoc.SetProperty('ProhibitDTD', FALSE);
   XmlDoc.Async := FALSE;
   XmlDoc.ValidateOnParse := FALSE;

   XmlDoc.Load(FileName);
   if ( XmlDoc.ParseError.ErrorCode <> 0 ) then
       raise Exception.Create(XmlDoc.ParseError.Reason);

   // This will display "note"
   ShowMessage('DocType: ' + XmlDoc.Doctype.Name);
   // This will display the embedded DTD as a string
   ShowMessage('DTD: ' + XmlDoc.Doctype.Xml);

   // These loops will display nothing
   for i := 0 to XmlDoc.Doctype.Entities.Length-1 do
      ShowMessage('Entity: ' + XmlDoc.Doctype.Entities[i].NodeName);
   for i := 0 to XmlDoc.Doctype.Notations.Length-1 do
      ShowMessage('Notation: ' + XmlDoc.Doctype.Notations[i].NodeName);
   for i := 0 to XmlDoc.Doctype.ChildNodes.Length-1 do
      ShowMessage('Child: ' + XmlDoc.Doctype.ChildNodes[i].NodeName);
end;
```

Is there a way to iterate over the DTD node structure using MSXML6?